# How to sync a table with a chart in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular, I am learning how to work with the ngx module.
I have a table (Ng2 table) that contains some data (username, email, age, etc..), the data for this table is hard-coded in a table.service.ts file.
I have a pie chart displaying the ages of the different users, what I want to do is sync the chart with the table. For example, if a user is deleted, the chart displays the changes immediately (one less user).
Note that I am sending the data from the table component to the chart component using `@Input()`, however it is always the same hard coded data.
Also, note that whenever a user is deleted (or added) it will disappear (or appear) from the table but the data file remains intact, so I'm not sure where is the data going or how does the table display new data.
What am I supposed to do here in order to sync the data? I went through many different concepts like observables, event emiters and promises, but I still don't know what to use. Where do I even begin?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use the same data for two views (ngModel, reactiveForm, service). Angular will automatically update